# Accuracy of the decimal number type versus the double type in .Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, rounding, rounding-error

Consider the following code:

```
    Dim doubleResult = (21 / 88) * 11
    Dim decimalResult = Decimal.Divide(21, 88) * 11
```

The `doubleResult` is 2.625, as it should.

The `decimalResult` is 2.6249999999999996, so when rounding this to two decimal places will give an incorrect result.

When I change the assignment to:

```
    Dim decimalResult = Decimal.Divide(21 * 11, 88)
```

The result is 2.625!

We adopted the decimal type in our application hoping that it would give us increased accuracy (it is a scoring program in which scores can have at most one digit behind the decimal separator). However, it seems that the decimal type just gives slightly incorrect results on other calculations than the double type does, due to the the fact that it is ten based, rather than two based.

So, how do we have to deal with this idiosyncrasies to avoid rounding errors as above?

Comment: I don't know the VB.NET conversion rules, but my guess is that the result of `Decimal.Divide` is being converted to `Double` before being multiplied by 11. The way `Decimal` is implemented in the CLR, it shouldn't be possible to get the result you are getting just using `Decimal`. Try using `11D` instead of `11`.

Comment: @siride using `11D` does not make a difference. The `decimalResult` *is* a decimal.

Comment: `Decimal` is really just a floating point number that uses base 10 instead of base 2. So it's always possible that you will get unround numbers, as you would with `Double`, but the conditions will be different. There's really no way around this because numbers have to fit in finite memory, even though they may be infinite. Still, for monetary calculations, `Decimal` is more likely to not have these types of rounding issues because monetary calculations mostly involve additional and subtraction of base 10 numbers.

Comment: 21 / 88 = 0.23863636363636363636363636363636.  Using either type is going to give you an approximation of the repeating fraction.  How the results appear is going to depend on the rounding.

Comment: @dbasnett So: how to implement a rounding strategy then?

Comment: @Dabblernl I'd use math.round.  The choice of data type is up to you.

Comment: @dbasnett Math.Round will give an incorrect result in some cases (2.62 rather than 2.63).

Comment: @Dabblernl "at most one digit behind the decimal separator" - you could multiply them all by ten so that you are only working with integers, thus eliminating one source of inaccuracy.

Comment: @dbasnett I do not follow you: 231/88 is *exactly* 2.625, which will round to 2.63. De initial decimal calculation is plainly inaccurate.

Comment: @Dabblernl: `Math.Round()` takes an argument to indicate rounding strategy. Pick one that works for you.

Comment: @Dabblernl - 21/88 = 0.2386363636363636363636363636...  Where did 231 come from?  Math.Round - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Precision  - has an overload that accepts how rounding happens.  I think you want MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero. see example below.

Answer (score 0):

Example of midpoint rounding

```
    Dim adec As Decimal = 231D
    adec /= 88D

    adec = Math.Round(adec, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: Did you mean to say `As Double` in the second example?